# How to make the `[per-mode=symbol]` parameter apply everywhere in `siunitx`?

Tags: siunitx

The title reveals the gist of my question. I simply don't want to have to include `[per-mode=symbol]` every single time I call `\SI{value}{unit}` for a unit which includes a fraction. How do I make this the default for a given document?

Comment: May I ask which version of siunitx you are using? The `\SI{}{}` style seems like the older version of the package. The new package uses `\qty{value}{unit}` to write numbers and units, `\unit{unit}` to express only units, and `\num{}` to write only numbers.

Comment: @Ginko-Mitten Thanks for pointing that out. I have no clue how to check package versions, but I know it comes from `texlive-full` from the stable Debian Bullseye repos. You know all the jokes about Debian being slow on updating their repos. ;)

Comment: check your `.log` file or type `tlmgr info siunitx` in your terminal to get this info. If you want the latest installation, try using the instructions on: https://fahim-sikder.github.io/post/installing-texlive-latest-ubuntu/. The instruction set is for 2021, but you can change the year to 2023 in each instruction code and get the latest version, if you wish. All the best. :)

Comment: @Ginko-Mitten Thanks! Super useful! God bless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the preamble you can do the following:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
```

That should make `/` as the default `per` symbol.